# JSF composite component value and <c:if>

Tags: jsf, jstl, composite-component

I have the following:

```
<c:set var="myMode" value="#{component.parent.attributes['xyz-mode']}"/>
```

where "xyz-mode" is from another composite component...
when I print its value using this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{myMode}" />
```

It prints it correctly, suppose the value is 3
But..in the same page, when I use c:if or c:when.. it does not evaluate the value correctly:

```
<c:choose>    
    <c:when test="#{myMode == 3}">
         <p:outputLabel value="mode is 3" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <p:outputLabel value="Otherwise" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The code prints the "Otherwise" case only.. not the "mode is 3"
Please note that the type of "xyz-mode" that is retrieved from the composite component is Integer..
Why this is happening..
It has been 10 days now and I am not finding the answer :( .. can anyone help please?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rendered` attribute to check the condition and print the value accordingly.

```
<p:outputLabel value="mode is 3" rendered="#{myMode == 3}" />
<p:outputLabel value="Otherwise" rendered="#{myMode != 3}" />
```

Hope it helps.