# "<c:if>" and "rendered" is not working at all

Tags: jsf, jstl, custom-component

I need to read a certain attribute from the parent component... but its not working at all, 
I tried 2 things to define the attribute using:
`<ui:param>`  and   `<c:set>`

and to read them I tried also 2 things:

`<ui:fragment>` and `<c:if test>`

but no luck
Here is the code:

```
 <ui:param name="panelName" value="#{component.parent.attributes.panelName}" />

 <c:set var="panelName2" value="{component.parent.attributes.panelName}" scope="view" />

<c:if test="#{panelName == 'abc'}">
anything
</c:if>

<ui:fragment rendered="#{panelName2 == 'abc'}">
Hellooo
</ui:fragment>
```

I am using JSF 2.2

Could anyone explain why this is happening please

Thanks in advance

Comment: When I use this,
<p:outputLabel value="#{panelName}"/>

 it prints it, but its not what I want, I want to check the value from the parent component and do different things accordingly..

Comment: A MCVE would be helpful. Nothing in the code indicates what component exactly `#{component}` is. Also, I have the strong feeling that this is a XY-problem. Please tell about the concrete functional requirement for which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution.

Comment: I have a primefaces panel that could have either fields inside it or data-tables, so if the panel mode is read only, I need to draw the fields within in read mode.. so:
if panelmode == 'read'
then draw <p:outputLabel..../>
else if panelmode ==  'edit'
then draw <p:inputText.... />
So in this case, the parent component is the panel and the inner component is <myField...> which could be any field type.. so its somehow dynamic to a level so thats why I need this.

Comment: So I have a drawField.xhtml and the page.xhtml... the page.xhtml contains:
<myPanel name="ABC">
<drawField name="fieldX" />
</myPanel>

In the drawField.xhtml... I ask for the parent component which is the "myPanel" then I need to access its mode which is an attribute in the myPanel custom component..
The fields within the panel and other components are drawn in different modes according to the myPanel mode.